# how disable use swap partition by processes , only if its really need

Tags: linux, swap, process-management

My embedded system has 2 GB RAM and 100 MB swap partition.
I recognize, after continues monitoring that average memory usage of RAM is ~50 %.
For some reason system start use SWAP memory and use almost 40 % of it (40 MB).
I want prevent such thing because my device flash has a big problem with number of writes and I need it for ~10 years of use.
After run these set of commands I get to list of processes that use SWAP :

```
for file in /proc/*/status ; do awk '/VmSwap|Name/{printf $2 " " $3}END{ print ""}' $file; done | sort -k 2 -n -r | less​
```

My  system file `/etc/sysctl.conf` confiured with parameter : `vm.swappiness=1` , so according articles I read it should use SWAP only if it really need. 
(I investigated the results with `vm.sappiness=0`, but didn't have results yet.)

I know that there is a way to prevent from specific processes use swap, but what is a correct one?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but with that setup, do you need the swap in the first place? 100 MB isn't that much on a 2 GB machine, so you could probably do without it, and avoid this issue too. Also, the amount of swap in use at one time doesn't tell how much writes go to the swap: some rarely-if-ever used data might end up in swap the first the memory is full, and if it's never modified, there are no further writes.

Comment: This sounds like a job for the `nice` family... [ionice](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ionice.1.html)  [nice](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nice.1.html)  [renice](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/renice.1.html)

Comment: You may also want to decrease verbosity level of logs in rsyslog configuration.

Comment: my system is embedded base very shrink Debian 8 based system , that has problem with number of writes/read per-block on his flash drive, but it run an application that use pretty more resources. This is a reason why we declare swap partition if system get to critical point it will use swap partition.

Answer (score 4):

You can set swappiness per process with [cgroups](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt)

```
echo 0 > /sys/fs/cgroup/<your custom group>/memory.swappiness
```

Anyway my advice is to use [zram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram) for compressed swapping in ram.

Comment: Just to add, this can also be achieved with the libcgroup and the cgset command.

Answer (score 0):

I test on two systems , where I detect previously use of 40% of SWAP option of :

```
vm.swappiness=0
```

This option really helped . I didn't see any use of swap for last 4 days